# Record Type Not Changing

Tags: contact, record-type

While logged in as the System Administrator and editing a contact, I see the option to change the contact's record type.  I click the change link and a new screen is displayed allowing me to choose a new record type.  I select the new record type from the list and click Save.

The edit screen is displayed again but the record type hasn't be changed.  No error or warning message is displayed at any time.  Disabling every trigger to eliminate any potential conflict hasn't helped.  From the Developer's Console, I am able to change the record type, just not from the web user interface.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm your steps:
1) Click Change next to record type
2) Select correct type
3) Click Continue
4) Click Save
5) Back on Saved Screen the record type is back to what it started at?

This sounds like it has to be a trigger that is setting the record type based on some criteria after it is saved again. Are you sure you deactivated all triggers?

Comment: This is a development sandbox, but I see the same effect in our Production environment.  I've just now commented out all triggers and deactivated all workflows.  The issue remains.  From the detail page of a contact, I click the "change" link next to the record type field.  The Contact Record Type Change screen appears.  I select a new one and click continue.  The detail screen reappears but the record type remains the old value.  If I change the record type in the developer's console, it changes successfully.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I no longer have access to the environment now as I'm with a new organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this issue which I just did. A possible reason would be that the Object "Edit" button has a VF override that does not allow it to change.